# I am getting no values from below Aura blank rows are seen

Tags: apex, lightning-aura-components, trigger, lightning, aura

Component:

```
 <aura:component controller="AB_Account" implements="force:appHostable,flexipage:availableForAllPageTypes,flexipage:availableForRecordHome,force:hasRecordId,forceCommunity:availableForAllPageTypes,force:lightningQuickAction" access="global" >
    
    <aura:attribute name="acc" type="Account"/>
    <aura:attribute name="columns" type="List"/>
    
    <aura:handler name="init" value="{!this}" action="{!c.doInit}"/>
   
    
    <div style="height: 300px">
        <lightning:datatable
                keyField="id"
                data="{! v.acc }"
                columns="{! v.columns }"
                hideCheckboxColumn="true"/>
    </div>
</aura:component>
```

Controller:

```
    ({
    doInit : function(component, event, helper) {
        
        console.log('$AB_Account Init Called');
        component.set("v.columns", [
            {label: 'Account name', fieldName: 'accountName', type: 'text'},
            {label: 'Opportunity name', fieldName: 'opportunityName', type: 'text'}
        ]);
        
       
        helper.helpfetchAccount(component);
    }
})
```

Helper:

```
({
    helpfetchAccount : function(component) {
        console.log('helper called')
        var action = component.get("c.getAccount");
        action.setCallback(this, function(response) {
            var state = response.getState();
            if (state == "SUCCESS") {
                component.set("v.acc", response.getReturnValue());
                console.log( response.getReturnValue());
            }
            else {
                console.log("Failed with state: " + state);
            }
        });
        $A.enqueueAction(action);
    } ,

})
```

Apex Controller Class:

```
    public class AB_Account 
{
    @AuraEnabled
    public static List<Account> getAccount()
    {
        System.debug('getAccount Called');
        List<Account> accs = [Select Name from Account];
        System.debug('$Accounts '+accs);
        return accs;
    }
}
```

Output:
[image: Output]

Can someone please point out the mistake I am making here.
Thank you in Advance. Sorry, I am new to Aura. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You didn't query the opportunity at all, and you didn't match up the field name to the returned data. As you can see, the rows are present, but not showing anything. For example, the account name should be:

```
        {label: 'Account Name', fieldName: 'Name', type: 'text'},
```